import failure matplotlib with Jupyter in VSCode
when trying to import matplotlib in my Jupyter notebook in VS Code, I get the following error:


ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
last) Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import matplotlib
File
c:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_init_.py:174
170 from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
172 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
173 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 174 from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
175 from matplotlib.cbook import sanitize_sequence
176 from matplotlib._api import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning
File
c:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook_init_.py:32
30 import matplotlib
31 from matplotlib import _api, _c_internal_utils
---> 32 from matplotlib._api.deprecation import (
33     MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, mplDeprecation)
36 @_api.deprecated("3.4")
37 def deprecated(*args, **kwargs):
38     return _api.deprecated(*args, **kwargs)
ImportError: cannot import name 'mplDeprecation' from
'matplotlib._api.deprecation'
(c:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_api\deprecation.py)

I am at a loss here. The current version is 3.8.3. Jupyter Extension is v2024.2.0 (switched from pre-release version which gave me the same error), Python is 3.10.11.
Everything pretty much worked until recently, until I upgraded matplotlib via pip due to some other mysterious behavior. However I am now also unable to downgrade, but this would be plan B anyhow. Any ideas what's the issue here?

It appears you have other related old pieces left behind from the upgrade process or some dependencies have not been updated to keep matching. The Jupyter stuff shouldn't matter here. Can you use Python in the terminal and see if you can import it there? I suspect not.  In the future using virtual environments would be advisable so you can update things in an environment and not affect your base installs on your system. These though some with more challenges and learning curves as you have to learn how to use them right. Installing the Anaconda Distribution is one such approach.

phew, okay... you are right, it doesn't work in the console either. Any idea how I can fix this with the current setup, though? Do you think it is advisable to do a complete re-install of Python from scratch? I usually avoid taking those drastic measures as to my experience they sometimes come with a number of unexpected and time-consuming consequences. I will have to look into virtual environments at some point, but unfortunately, I'm short on time atm, so I was hoping for a quick fix, some stupid mistake I made, etc. Anyways, I moved to Colab in the meantime.

Yes, drastic measures are never a good idea. It often can make things worse. And I understand about the time issue. Glad you at least found a work around for now. Another two options options are spelled out here. I would suggest sticking with the MyBinder-served full Python kernel mentioned there. However, if you are just looking to use matplotlib, JupyterLite is a nice option. Just always be careful to give it time to start the kernels properly.  As for a fix. I'm not sure about anything other than cleaning ...

 things out. And what to clean out is then the question. I didn't find good advice yet. I did find other saying to downgrade again, see here. Any chance you recall what you had? And here said to upgrade Python to 3.11 and update pip and matplotlib.
